# Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc,

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer2.x

When I open video More then 2 time  it will give error when i open video less then 2 time it will work properly

i can not find any solution so if you have any solution please help me out

```
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, null, -1, null, [480, 270, -1.0], [-1, -1])
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:479)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.reinitializeCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1261)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1111)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:552)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:647)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:536)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
     Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, null, -1, null, [480, 270, -1.0], [-1, -1])
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:753)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:474)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.reinitializeCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1261) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1111) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:552) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:647) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:536) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65) 
     Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Failed to initialize OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, error 0xfffffff4
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_setup(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.<init>(MediaCodec.java:1786)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.createByCodecName(MediaCodec.java:1767)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:802)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:745)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:474) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.reinitializeCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1261) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1111) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:552) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:647) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:536) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

here is exoplayer,minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion version

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.1'
 minSdkVersion 16
 targetSdkVersion 28
```

Here is My video play code:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_item, container, false);
                simpleExoPlayerView = view.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
                simpleExoPlayerView.setTag("view" + position);
                player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, new DefaultTrackSelector(), new DefaultLoadControl());
                Uri mediaUri = Uri.parse(urlList.get(position));
                mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(
                        new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("media-slider-view")).
                        createMediaSource(mediaUri);
                simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
                player.prepare(mediaSource, true, true);
                player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                player.seekTo(0, 0);
```

Comment: found any solution?

Answer (score 8):

Are you releasing and reinitializing the player each time you move from one video to the other? If not try to do so. If does not works the best you can do is to reproduce the behaviour on the exoplayer demo to be sure that the problem is just inside your implementation otherwise open a bug issue to the exopleyer project describing how to reproduce the error on the exoplayer demo project

Answer (score 6):

try to stop and release ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance onResume, onStop and onPause.

I tried this and it works perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Why do you have two times. player.release() ? is not enough with one ?

Comment: You are right one is enough :)

Answer (score 6):

This answer is for special case.
If you use **[scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy)**, turn it off or scale down with `max-size` option. (ex. `scrcpy -m 1080`) Some devices cause this problem with scrcpy.

Comment: I would never gussed that, Thanks.

Comment: WTF ? how did you arrive to that ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was releasing player on fragment's **onDestroy()**. Moving it to **onPause()** worked